# Request Token Fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: rest-api

Just set up a new API Integration account and connected it to our Exact Target account. Every call to the REST refresh token endpoint returns 401 Unauthorized.

We have another account/API Integration with identitical setup that works fine.

Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: You are sending the wrong or invalid refresh token

Comment: This is a first time request. We don't have a token yet. Just sending client id and client secret.

Comment: Could you post the code that you have written so far that is failing. Of course leave the client id and client secret blank or change to dummy values. Just want to see what the request looks like. Since you have one that works, have you analyzed the headers of both requests to see if there is anything slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses. It ended up being due to IP restrictions. Doh!

Comment: How did you find out about that? I think I have the same issue, should I call them on the phone or is it something I could fix by myself?